# Is there a way to paint onto a JPanel from an async method?

Tags: java, swing, firebase, awt

I am writing a Java based game using Swing and Firebase. I store all my players in a list, and when any of them move the `onChildChanged(...)` callback (see below) is fired. Since this is async, I obviously can't set any variables that are out of the function's scope. This is was all fine, until I needed to actually paint this player to the screen.

Since I extend a `JPanel` and overwrite it's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` I have to do all my drawing within this method (or at least thats what I've been told). The problem is I need to draw this player from inside the callback, and this is what I don't know how to do.

I have tried to "export" the `Graphics g` object to a global variable, and then use that variable within the async function but this yielded no results. Maybe because it isn't actually drawing to the JPanel's canvas?

So I have a class something like this:

```
class Screen extends JPanel {

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // All my painting stuff goes here
}

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            // This is the callback
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
                      // Draw the player
                }
            }
        });

}
```

EDIT: forgot to mention that I am also calling `repaint()` on every game tick (60 times a second). I don't know if this changes anything but just in case :)

So I want to be able to paint the player either within the callback or paint it in the `paintComponent()` method, and I'm wondering how this can be done.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're willing to take over complete control of the painting process, by using a `BufferStratetgy`, the "general" as is "no", but it's more complicated then that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't paint anywhere except within the paintComponent method. So the solution is:

- Update the model fields that are used to tell the GUI what to paint.
- If this update will directly affect the GUI in any other way, such as update text fields, labels, JTables and such, then this data change should be performed on the EDT by placing it into the event queue within a Runnable passed into `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`
- Then call `repaint()`
- The GUI will then use those fields and do all painting on the Swing event thread.

Note that `repaint()` is one of the few Swing methods that can be called **off** of the EDT.

---

> I am little confused as to what you mean by updating the model's fields though haha, could you maybe clarify that?

If you're creating any complex GUI, you'll likely use a model - view type of structure (such as M-V-C for model-view-controller) where you separate program logic, the model portion, from the GUI, the view. The view depicts the state of the model and allows for user interaction, so I'm talking about state fields.

For example, if you have a game with animation, the model would represent the location of the players, the state of the players (health, weapons, stock), their behaviors, .... while the view would draw all of this based on the model's state.

Comment: Okay, so I can't paint from outside the paintComponent method. I am little confused as to what you mean by updating the model's fields though haha, could you maybe clarify that? (I am still kind of a Java/Swing noob).